# Crontab and Home Brew

Tags: bash, shell, cron, macos-mojave

I am trying to execute a backup.sh script from crontab on Mac OSX Mojave. I installed webkit2png via brew install webkit2png and that seemed to work fine.

I have a test command working fine from the terminal. I have made the file Chmod 755 and executable. This command works from terminal: `webkit2png -F -W 1600 -d --delay=5 /Users/sof/backups https://www.google.com`

My crontab runs and when it does run, it says webkit2png command not found in the mail log.

Why would cron not be able to find it if my user can find it and run it in terminal. I think my path is correct so I am unsure what to try.

backup.sh contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
webkit2png -F -W 1600 -d --delay=5 /Users/sof/backups https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Not familiar with macos, but you might add a PATH at the top of the crontab file (`man 5 crontab)`. That, or give the full path to `webkit2png `or the shell script in the crontab file.